# Page numbers are not rendering in Pagination control spfxwebpart react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, fluent-ui

I am using Fluent UI pagination control. Setting page count dynamically using state variable. But, it is not setting in the  initial page load once webpart loaded. Showing only "Next" and "Previous" buttons, no page numbers. I'm setting "totalPages" state variable for Page count property in the constructor. Data is getting rendered (intialised state variable in construtor )but not pages.

here is the image for reference:
[image]

Please let me know where am I going wrong and where I should initialize the state variable in order to show the page numbers in the initial page load?

Below is my `.tsx` code:

```
export default class RegListView extends React.Component<IRegListViewProps,IstateItems,{}> 

{

constructor(props:any)
{

  super(props);

  this.state={
    allRegulations: this.props.regulationItems,
    totalPages:this.props.regulationItems.length/5,
    currentPage:0,

  };
  
  console.log("Regulations: " +this.props.regulationItems.length);

}

private _onPageChange=(Page:number):void =>

  {   

    this.setState({currentPage: Page});
    console.log("Current Page: "+this.state.currentPage);
    this.setItemsToPage(Page);

  }

private setItemsToPage=(Page:number) =>

  {    

    let nextPage=Page+1;
    if(Page<Math.ceil(this.props.regulationItems.length/5))
    {
      this.setState({allRegulations:this.props.regulationItems.slice(Page*5,nextPage*5)});
    }

}
```

In Render method:

```
<div>

          <DetailsList
            columns={[
              { key: 'Col1', name: 'Detail Page',fieldName:'ITD2_DetailPage2', minWidth: 70, maxWidth: 100,isResizable :true,
                onRender:(regulationItem)=>{

                  return(<Link href={regulationItem.ITD2_DetailPage2}   target='_blank'>{regulationItem.FieldValuesAsText.FileLeafRef}</Link>)
                }
              },
              { key: 'Col2', name: 'Regulation Code',fieldName:'ITD2_RegulationCode', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true },
              { key: 'Col3', name: 'Master Language', fieldName:'ITD2_MasterLanguage',minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true},
              { key: 'Col4', name: 'Document Author',fieldName:'ITD2_DocumentAuthor', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true },
              { key: 'Col5', name: 'Regulation Type',fieldName:'ITD2_RegulationType', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true},
              { key: 'Col6', name: 'Regulation Title EN',fieldName:'ITD2_RegulationTitleEn', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true },
              { key: 'Col7', name: 'Regulation Title IT',fieldName:'ITD2_RegulationTitleIt', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true },
              { key: 'Col8', name: 'Paper Work Status',fieldName:'ITD2_Status', minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 200,isResizable :true  }
            ]} 
            items={this.state.allRegulations.slice(this.state.currentPage*5,this.state.currentPage+1*5)}
            compact={true}
            >   
         </DetailsList>
        </div>
      <div>
        <Pagination
        selectedPageIndex={this.state.currentPage}
        pageCount={this.state.totalPages}
        itemsPerPage={5}
        totalItemCount={regulationItems.length}
        format={"buttons"}      
        onPageChange={this._onPageChange}
         >
        </Pagination>
          </div>
```

Please respond ASAP.